# stacked barplot in R conditional coloring

Tags: r

I'm dealing with a data-frame in R that looks like this

```
test <- data.frame(c(1:4),c(5:8),c(9:12),c(13:16))
names(test) <- c("position","totalA","totalB","totalC")
```

No I want to create a stacked barplot, where all bars are in black, except for 1 value of position, there I want different colors for 'totalA', 'totalB' and 'totalC'

This is what I did to create the barplot

```
test.transposed <- setNames(data.frame(t(test[,-1])), test [,1])
barplot(as.matrix(test.transposed))
```

so now all bars are conditionally colored, but this should only be the case when position == 2. For the rest all bars should be black.

Beware I cannot use ggplot2 to do this ...

Comment: So, in the transposed version of the data / plot, you want 3 black bars and the 2nd one to be in color?

Comment: indeed. That's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hacky way to do it:

```
test.transposed2 <- rbind(test.transposed, 'total' = apply(test.transposed,2,sum))
test.transposed2[1:3, -2] = 0
test.transposed2[4,2] = 0
barplot(as.matrix(test.transposed2[c(4,1,2,3),]))
```

[image]